# Approved memory cards for nikon d3100

Tags: nikon, memory-card, sdcard, memory-card-size

From many sources I find that Nikon supports only 16 GB (not 32GB) SanDisk sdcards.

This is the source of the information https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/16921/~/approved-memory-cards---d3100

Why 32 GB SanDisk card is not supported ?
What if I buy 32 GB SanDisk memory card of class 10 ?

Comment: 32Gb Sandisk **SDXC** cards _are_ supported. Avoid SDHC cards and you will have no problems.

Comment: Is class 10 fast enough ?

Comment: In most cases yes, it should be fine.

Comment: Depending on how you are shooting (JPEG, RAW, Raw+JPEG) the file sizes will get pretty big.  When I started shooting RAW on my D3200 I found that some cards I used to use were lagging as it tried to write out the info.  I've stopped using the cards rated for write times under 45Mbps and have stocked up with the Extreme which are rated for 80Mbps.  Of course the Extreme pro are faster....  And I am using 32GB exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the title of the support article which is **"What memory cards have been tested for use in the Nikon D3100?"** and not "What memory cards have known to be incompatible with the Nikon D3100?"

Nikon are not saying that the 32GB SanDisk cards (SDHC/SDXC) are not compatible, only that Nikon have not tested them.

SanDisk appear to have tested their products with the D3100 and compatible products include a selection of cards including 32GB SDXC and SDHC variants.  The full list can be obtained through their [Compatibility Checker](http://pct1.sandisk.com/Default.aspx).